# PHP logic check failure to adjust CSS class

Tags: php, css

I have a simple log in screen that is a sticky form . I am trying to get the log in boxes to turn red when the form is submitted but the input field is left blank. I am getting some really strange behaviour where two of the fields do this correctly and others seem to be random.The photo on the left below shows what happens after the page loads and submit is hit. The second photo on the right shows the 'random' behaviour after I enter some details- hit submit, and then go back and delete these details and resubmit again. All the data is stored in php global variables i.e. not from database at present.

[image: after submit is hit]   [image]

```
 <!doctype html>


   <html>

     <head>
      <title>Sign Up Report</title>
      <meta charset= "utf-8">
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="login.css"> 
     </head> 
  <body>

     <?php
     $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
     $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
     $address = $_POST['address'];
     $city = $_POST['city'];
     $zip = $_POST['zip'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
     $presentForm = false;
     $user = $_POST['user'];
     $level = implode(", ",$_POST['level']);
     $subjects = implode(", ",$_POST['subject']);

     $required="";
     $userError = "" ;
     $levelError = "" ;
     $subjectsError = "" ;
     $errorMessage="";



     //check to see if the form has been submitted and that all the   required data is present if so then report success to user
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
     {
       if (((!empty($firstName))) && ((!empty($lastName))) && ((!empty($address))) && ((!empty($city))) && ((!empty($email))) && ((!empty($telephone))) && ((!empty($zip))) && ((!empty($level))) && ((!empty($subjects)))) 
         {

     echo '<style> h1 {text-decoration: none; margin-left:20px;} #confirmation { background-color: white; border: solid black 2px; margin: 15px; background-image: url("../Images/tutorTeam.png")  } p {color:blue; margin-left: 10; padding:10px; } li { margin-left: 15px; } img { padding: 20px;}</style>';
     echo '<h1>Thank you ' . $firstName . ' for signing up!</h1>';
     echo '<div id="confirmation">';
     echo '<p>Please review the following details to ensure they are correct: </p>';
     echo '<li>You are a  <b>' . $user . '</b></li><br>';
     echo '<li>Your address is <b>' . $address . $city . $zip .'</b></li><br>';
     echo '<li>Your contact number is <b>' . $telephone . '</b></li><br>';
     echo '<li>Your email is <b>' . $email . '</b></li><br>';
     echo '<li>The subject(s) you selected- <b>' . $subjects . '</b></li><br>';
     echo '<li>Your tuition level(s) <b>' . $level . '</b></li>';
     echo '<a href="../index.html"><img src="../Images/confirm.png" id="return"></a>';
     echo '<a href="tutorSignUp.php"><img src="../Images/edit.png" id="return"></a>';
     echo '</div>';


     $presentForm = false;

      }else{


     $presentForm=true;
     $required = "req";
     $levelError = "level selection required" ;
     $subjectsError = "subject selection required" ;
     $errorMessage="Please enter the data that is missing to sign up";

          }
      }

      if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
      {
        $presentForm=true;
      }

        if($presentForm) 
         {
           ?> 
             <div id="container">

             <section id="top"> 

               <a href="../index.html">
                <img id="back" src="../images/back.png" height="40px">
               </a>

              <img id="logo" src="../images/tutorTeamLogo.png" height="40px"> 

             </section>


             <section id="main">

              <p><span class="error"><?php echo $errorMessage?></span> </p>  
              <p>Are you a tutor or customer? </p>

              <form  method="POST" action=" <?php echo  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >

              <select name="user">
                <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
                <option value="Tutor">Tutor</option>
              </select>

                <p>Please complete to sign up.</p>

            <section id="details">

             <div class="tablerow">
               <p>First name:</p> 
               <p><input class="inputBox <?php if(empty($firstName) &&   (isset($_POST['submit']))) echo 'errorBox' ?> " type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>" ></p>

               <span class="error">* <?php echo $required;?></span>
             </div>

           <div class="tablerow">
            <p>Last name:</p>
            <p><input class="inputBox <?php if(empty($lastName) &&  (isset($_POST['submit']))) echo 'errorBox' ?> " type="text" name="lastName"  value="<?php echo $lastName; ?> "></p>

            <span class="error">* <?php echo $required;?></span>
          </div>

           <div class="tablerow">
            <p>Address:</p>    
            <p><input class="inputBox <?php if(empty($address) &&  (isset($_POST['submit']))) echo 'errorBox' ?> " type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?> "></p>

            <span class="error">* <?php echo $required;?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="tablerow">
            <p>city: </p>      
            <p><input class="inputBox <?php if(empty($city) &&  (isset($_POST['submit']))) echo 'errorBox' ?> " type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?> "></p>
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $required; ?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="tablerow">
            <p>Zip: </p>      
            <p> <input class="inputBox <?php if(empty($zip) &&  (isset($_POST['submit']))) echo 'errorBox' ?> " type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip; ?> "></p>

         <span class="error">* <?php echo $required; ?></span>
         </div>

         <div class="tablerow">
            <p>Telephone:</p>  
            <p><input class="inputBox <?php if(empty($telephone) &&  (isset($_POST['submit']))) echo 'errorBox' ?> " type="tel" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?> "></p>

           <span class="error">* <?php echo $required; ?></span>
        </div>

        <div class="tablerow">
          <p>Email:</p>  
          <p><input class="inputBox <?php if(empty($email) &&  (isset($_POST['submit']))) echo 'errorBox' ?> " type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></p>

          <span class="error">* <?php echo $required; ?></span>
         </div>

        </section>

       <img src="../Images/dubaiZones.png" id="dubaiMap">

       <p>Tutoring level <span class="error">* <?php echo $levelError;?>  </span>   </p>

         <input type="checkbox" name="level[]" value="Nursery" >Nursery<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="level[]" value="Primary"  >Primary<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="level[]" value="Secondary" >Secondary<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="level[]" value="ALevel" >College/A Level       <br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="level[]" value="Undergraduate" >Undergraduate<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="level[]" value="Postgraduate" >Postgraduate<br> 


      <p> Subject specialism(s)<span class="error">* <?php echo $subjectsError;?></span></p>

        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="English">English<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Maths">Maths<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Physics">Physics<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Chemistry">Chemistry<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Biology">Biology<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="History">History<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Geography">Geography<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Religious Studies">R.E.<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="French">French<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="German">German<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Spanish">Spanish<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Computing">Computing<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Business">Business<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Economics">Economics<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Classics">Classics<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Music">Music<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Art">Art<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="subject[]" value="Art">Languages<br>
        <br>

     <textarea id="textArea" name="comments" rows="10" cols="48">Additional Information...</textarea>
       <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="submit" id="submit">
   </form>

  </section>
     <br>
      <br>
       <br>

<footer> 
   <table id="tableContainer">
      <tr id="end">
        <td id="tableCell">Website design and coding provided by Technology in Learning 2016

        Copyright Technology in Learning <img id="til" src="../Images/company.png" height="12"  width="12">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </footer>    
  </div>

 <?php
   }
 ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS file for reference

```
#container {

background-image: url(..//Images/backgroundPic.jpg);
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-size: cover;
width: 1000px;
border-style: ridge;
border-width: 5px;
}

h1,h2 {
text-decoration: underline;

}

p {
font-weight: bold;
}


body { 

  font-family:      Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:        medium; 
  background-color: #F1EBEB;

 }


/* Header */

#top{

 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: white;
 background-image: url(../images/tutorteam.png);
 height: 50px;
 width: 1000px;
 font-size:  1em;

 } 



 #top img  {
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;


}



#details{
display: table;
padding: 10px;

}

#details p{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:top;
padding: 3px;

}
div.tablerow {
display:table-row

}

div.tablerow p:first-child {

text-align: right;
}


#logo {

float:right;
margin-left: 4px;
margin-top :2px;
}

#back
{
float: left;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-top: 2px;

}



#main {

 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 background-color: white;

}

#tableContainer {

position: absolute;
left:300px;
bottom:-350px;
display:table;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
border-spacing:10px;
 font-size:  0.25em;


}

#footer {

display:table-row;

}

#tableCell {

  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:  top;

}



#dubaiMap {

float: right;
position: relative;
right: 20px;
top: -200px;

}


#signUp {


margin-left: 110px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
height: 90px;

}

#submit {

    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 420px;
    margin-left: 20px;

    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;

}

textarea {

    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 250px;
    right: 175px;
    border: 3px solid #4CAF50;
    font-size: 14px
}

.error  {

color:red;
font-weight:normal;

}

input.errorBox{
    background-color: #FCD9D9;

}
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: thank you for the link . I am going to review at more length and continue editing to ensure it is better. Any thoughts on the problem would be greatly appreciated I am only a beginner really and I find PHP pretty tough to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to anyone who had a look at this. I am new to PHP so please excuse me. I went line by line character by character through the code and spotted the problem.

This code **did not work** and produced the unwanted response of not colouring red when the logic check was passed:

```
<div class="tablerow">

   <p>Zip:</p>      
   <p> <input class="inputBox <?php if(empty($zip) && (isset($_POST['submit']))) echo 'errorBox' ?> " type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip; ?> "></p>
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $required; ?></span>
</div>
```

This code **did work** and produced correct response of  colouring red when the logic check was passed:

```
 <div class="tablerow">

  <p>Zip:</p>
  <p><input class="inputBox <?php if(empty($zip) && (isset($_POST['submit']))) echo 'errorBox' ?> " type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip; ?>" ></p>
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $required;?></span>
</div>
```

Cue many hours of frustration later and getting several people to review ,who also could not spot anything.... the answer , take a look at the final part of the non-working code as apposed to the correct working one!

```
"<?php echo $zip; ?> "> 
"<?php echo $zip; ?>"
```

I have the upmost respect for anyone who programs in this language. I am guessing that the error that is produced is because of not leaving empty characters at the end of a string to avoid SQL injection attacks?